# Intuition behind Riemann integrabillity and sequences of partitions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration

I started to self-study measure theory and as a review the book Im using(Rana) begin explaining some theorems on Riemann Integrals and im trying to understand to the fullest the intuition and proofs of the next theorem:

Let $f$ be a Riemann integrble function on $[a,b]$, then there exists a sequence of partitions $(\pi_n)_n$ such that $\pi_n\subset \pi_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Im not even sure how to start, besides noticing that since f is Riemann integrable $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=sup\{L(\pi,f)\}=inf\{U(\pi,f)\}$ where $\pi$ is a partition of $[a,b]$. Then we can choose $(\pi_{n}^{1})_{n},(\pi_{n}^{2})_{n}$ such that $lim$ $U(\pi_{n}^{1},f)$=$lim$ $L(\pi_{n}^{2},f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ as n tends to $\infty$ and such that $lim$ $U(\pi_{n},f)=$$lim$ $L(\pi_{n},f)=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$.

After that Im stuck. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Think about what happens to $L(\pi, f)$ when you take a finer or a coarser partition and similarly for $U(\pi, f)$.

Comment: What exactly is the full statement of the theorem? As written, there is no connection between $f$ and the sequence of partitions, and RRL's answer below seems to be the best interpretation of your question. I went through the first chapter of the book but I can't find any related theorem or exercise, so a more precise citation would also help.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Do you mean to say that there is a sequence $\pi_n$ such that $\pi_n\subset \pi_{n+1}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} L(\pi_n, f) =\lim_{n\to\infty} U(\pi_n, f) =\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, dx$?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, thats the full question but I thought that there were separated statements, maybe is because of my english but I thought that the first part of the problem was to show that if f is Riemann integrable then I could find a sequence of partitions s.t $ \pi_{n} \subset \pi_{n+1}$.

Comment: Ok then please edit the question accordingly. I have given a close vote with the reason "unclear what you are asking". Perhaps the close vote can be retracted after your edit.

Comment: Also your question is not difficult to prove. Use the fact that given any $\epsilon >0$ there is a partition $\pi_{\epsilon} $ such that $U(\pi_\epsilon, f) - L(\pi_\epsilon, f) <\epsilon $.

Comment: I edited the post sir! And Im not pretty sure if I could use what youre saying because doing that Im not constructing a partition that guarantees that $\pi_{n}\subset\pi_{n+1}$ or am I?